# JSP Page hidden field value not updating in same browser different tabs

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, hidden-field

I am using a spring MVC application.In the JSP page i am using a hidden field to persist the data in client side. Its a application for display the employee details.And based on the employeee status I need to disable or enable the fields in the JSP page.If I open different status employees in two tabs of the same browser(FF), the hidden field value is not updating.

In JSP page

```
<div id="main">
    <form:form modelAttribute="employeeModel" id="employeeModelform">
    <form:hidden path="employeerStatus" id="employeeStatusId" />
------
    </form:form>
</div>
```

In Contoller

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/{screen}/{employeeid}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getEmployeeBasicPage(
            @PathVariable(value = "employeeid") String employeeid,
            @PathVariable(value = "screen") String screen, Model model,
            HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        return employeeBasicPage(employeeid, screen, null, model, session);

    }
```

What are the possible ways to keep different hidden field values for different tabs of the same browser.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hidden field values are printed when the page loads.  You can only update them by reloading the page (aside from doing something in Javascript on the clientside, Ajax maybe). You should probably really think hard about why you feel you need to do this, because there is undoubtedly a better (even more correct) way to do it than with hidden fields.  Like, for instance, just keep the value in the session on the serverside rather than even putting it in a hidden field.  If the thing is part of the session scope there's probably no need to print it into a form at all.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Here my actual problem is if I open different employee details in different tab of the same browser, the hidden value is not changing for the specific browser tab instance.For example Expected result :for employee1- all fields in the pages are editable.For employee2 - all fields are diabled.But actual result is i am not able to edit both employee details.The 'employeeStatusId' hidden field is remains unchanged in all tab instances.